# Laravel DB query gives a set of results different from direct MySQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

My DB is:

```
|category_id|category_slug |category_name |parent_category_id|
|1          |Main Category1|Main Category1|0                 |
|2          |Main Category2|Main Category2|0                 | 
|3          |Sub Category1 |Sub Category1 |1                 |
|4          |Sub Category2 |Sub Category2 |1                 |
|5          |Sub Category3 |Sub Category3 |2                 |
```

I am trying to execute the following query in MySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM categories AS subcategory 
JOIN categories AS parent ON parent.category_id = subcategory.parent_category_id 
WHERE subcategory.category_display_type = 'sidebar'
  AND subcategory.category_visibility = 1
```

like so:

```
class SidebarnavComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $params = DB::table('categories as subs')->join('categories as cats', function($join){
                $join->on('subs.parent_category_id', '=', 'cats.category_id')
                ->where('subs.category_display_type', '=', 'sidebar')
                ->where('subs.category_visibility', '=', 1);
    })->get();


        $view->with('subcategories', $params);

    }
```

the problem is that I get different set of results.

When I use the first query directly in MySQL I get the following:

```
category_id
category_id1
category_title
category_title1
category_slug
category_slug1
.......
```

when I execute the second query in my laravel application I get the following set of results:

```
category_id
category_title
category_slug
.......
```

this basically means that I cannot access all necessary columns.

So what I need to be able to do is to build URI for my subcategories in the following way:

```
category_slug1/category_slug
```

where `category_slug1` is main category slug and `category_slug` is subdirectory slug. The problem is that I only get the main category slug and cannot get slug for my subcategory in URI.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am new to laravel and at the moment do not really know much, so please help me if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$data = DB::table('categories AS subcategory')
        ->join('categories AS parent', 'parent.category_id', '=', 'subcategory.parent_category_id')
        ->where('subcategory.category_display_type', '=', 'sidebar')
        ->where('subcategory.category_visibility', '=', 1)
        ->select('subcategory.category_slug AS category_slug1', 'parent.category_slug AS category_slug')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi Naincy, i get the following error: 'code'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subcategory.parent_category_id ' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `subcategory`.*, `parent`.* from `categories` as `subcategory` inner join `categories` as `parent` on `parent`.`category_id` = `subcategory`.`parent_category_id ` where `subcategory`.`category_display_type` = sidebar and `subcategory`.`category_visibility` = 1)

Comment: @AlexB You can change it as per your DB ... that is something I have taken from your question only... please see the exact field name from your DB

Comment: I fixed the typo, but the results that I get is the same so I only get the results for main categories and what I actually need is to have access to both categories and subcategories to be able to build the URI which will contain category_slug/subcategory_slug. Just to clarify both category_slug and subcategory_slug is the same column 'category_slug' but the dependency should kick in and separate the results.

Comment: in select you can mention all the specific column names that you want to retrieve

Comment: Let me update my question, so that you can see the DB structure, I think it will make more sense.

Comment: Perfect, all works now as intended, thank you for your help